# REACT NATIVE - Expo AV didJustFinish

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm currently working on an application in React Native. I need to be able to read and manage audios for my project.
I find the documentation for Expo AV rather badly done, there is a lack of examples of use.

To make it simple, I want to get the didJustFinish value (boolean). To do so, I created a loop using setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate but I don't understand how to get the didJustFinish value back afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution.
Here's an example:

```
yourSoundObject.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate((playbackStatus) => {
    console.log(playbackStatus.didJustFinish)
    console.log(playbackStatus.positionMillis)
})
```

playbackStatus is a property that is only added in the function called by setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate.
For ease of use I've done this in an anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to also add `progressUpdateIntervalMillis` in the options of your sound object to receive updates, because `didJustFinish` only fires once at the end of your your audio session.

So with your code, it will only check in the beginning and always return false.